# why is this nav broken on firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, html, webkit, cross-browser

Can you guys point out what I am doing wrong on with the navigation on this site? It works fine on webkit, but not firefox!

http://datatables.dyndns-web.com/
[image]

vs intended
[image]

Comment: What/how is it broken? What is your desired result? We need some more information, plz :)

Comment: It looks all funky.. Ill upload image now.

Comment: In my humble opinion, if you're going to base your work off of webkit and HTML5 you need a better overview of the consequences. If you use HTML5 structure, make sure you do what's necessary to provide the same styling for that structure on browsers like Firefox and IE. This is a "no problem" if you started coding it in Firefox with a normal div ul li structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The NAV-tag isn't a block-element by default in current versions of Presto, Trident and Gecko. Only WebKit has a default stylesheet for HTML5-elements included already. You should use a basic-/reset-CSS to format all HTML5-elements.

See: http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/

BTW, if someones asking for an image, you should upload an image of the desired result, not one of the broken view…